# Binding for Localization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, behavior

I'm working on a solution to a localization problem.  This isn't the normal language localisation.

```
<Label Content="{Binding myDictionary[A Test], FallbackValue=A Test}"/>
```

In practice the above code calls into the Dictionary in the view model, which is declared as

```
public Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary
```

The problem is that I have to define the string "A Test" twice in the label.
once as in the index in the binding, and again in the FallbackValue.

What I would like to end up with is something that looks like this...

```
<Label Content="{Binding myDictionary[A Test]}"/>
```

At the moment what happens when I do this is that the Xaml designer in Visual studio can't resolve myDictionary (as it won't know the datacontext so can't hook up to the viewmodel where it's defined) this means that the label will display as blank, which won't will make visual design harder.

I've looked into calling a static method however for myDictionary to function properly, it needs to be instantiated in the view model.

Is there a way of having either the index value "A Test" show up in the designer without having to use a fallback value?

The goal is to be able to have the content refreshed if the value in `myDictionary[A Test]` is updated (In reality myDictionary is observable)

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [WPF localization extension project](https://github.com/SeriousM/WPFLocalizationExtension). Even if you don't use it directly (there are hooks to get localized values from any data source), implementing this via a markup extension might be a better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

> as it won't know the datacontext so can't hook up to the viewmodel where it's defined

Not so.... One can use a design time only context by specifying it in the page's meta data atttributes such as:

```
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type viewModels:MainVM}}"
```

by doing that you can setup a design time only dictionary to use.

---

Read about here in MSDN magazine:

[MVVM - Maximizing the Visual Designer’s Usage with Design-Time Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn169081.aspx)

*Note one can still use the Blend namespaces in non Blend editors such as Visual Studio.* Otherwise don't be afraid to use/learn Blend as needed.

---

If from your actual VM with real data, in design mode its good to ignore certain objects/actions which may cause issues. Here is a check to determine if the action is *in design mode*, if it is not then it executes the block, otherwise it is ignored because it is in design mode.

```
if (!DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
```

Comment: ooOOOooo.   That looks interesting, I'm going to take a deeper look into that one and see if it can solve my problem.

Comment: @ColinDawson The Blend editor also has ways to *mock* data which visual studio does not have.

Comment: The DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode isn't any help for me, as I would need to call that from inside my viewmodel.  Of course my view model won't won't be able to ge to "this" in the right context.

Comment: I think my whole approach to this problem feels wrong.  Might have to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is localise the application, but instead of using resource files like MS wants, I want to use a database, and have the be able to update the strings on the fly.  I mean literally have the string change in front of your eye's if you the localisation lookup table is altered.

Comment: @ColinDawson I would recommend that you bind to a generic Dictionary/list/observable collection property *which adhere's to INotifyPropertychanged' and then simply swap out the list with a new one extracted from the db as needed. Note you may need to individually call the `PropertyChanged("MyTitleLabelText") as needed when the whole language is swapped out.

Comment: @Colin pass in a link to the main view to use with the IsInDesignView while on the VM.

Comment: Been thinking about this and looking at alternatives.  I think I've found a viable solution using a Markup extension.  This will let me pull the dictionary from the datacontext, and also allow the text to be visible if the dictionary isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle this IMO is with [a custom markup extension](http://www.wpftutorial.net/localizemarkupextension.html) placed within [a custom namespace](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and), it allows you to write XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Translate 'Hello World!'} />
```

What the `Translate` extension class returns is entirely up to you, typically you have it do a look-up into a Dictionary using the provided string as the index and, if it doesn't find it, just returns the string itself.

One of the nice things about this particular implementation is that it adds a listener to the Translation manager for every binding that is made, so they all automatically update at run-time whenever the current language is changed.

The one thing you do have to keep in mind though is to place the Translate extension class itself within its own project. Not sure why, it seems to be a bug in VS, but XAML files don't seem to be able to use custom markup extensions declared in the same project.